# How to check size of a Json array using a DTO object?

Tags: java, junit, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I need to get the size of the "description" array, convert to object dto. I need to check with rest assured if my array "description" contains at least 1 element inside. How do I do that?
My Json

```
{
"success": true,
"description": [
    {
        "a": "xxx",
        "a": 5,
        "a": "xxx",
        "a": "xx",
        "aaa": [
            {
                "b": 247,
                "b": "BR",
                "b": "CPF",
                "b": 3
            }
        ],
        "ccc": 3
    }
]
}
```

My code

```
public class Name extends Base {
private final String UrlString= "resource";

@Test
public void teste() {
    ResponseDTO responseDTO = given()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)

            .headers("utoken", utoken)
            .pathParam("name",name)

            .when()
            .get(UrlString)
            .then()
            .statusCode(is(statusok))
            .extract().as(ResponseDTO.class);
            validade(responseDTO);

}

public void validade(ResponseDTO responseDTO) {
    assertTrue(responseDTO.isSuccess());
}
```

My DTO

```
public class ResponseDTO {

  private boolean success;
  private List description;

  getters/setters
}
```

Comment: If it needs to be done on DTO object why don't you make list size validation in validate method? Like this
`public void validade(ResponseDTO responseDTO) {
    assertTrue(responseDTO.isSuccess());
    assertTrue(responseDTO.getDescription().size()>=1);
}`

Comment: Thank you for your information John Smith. I got it